# Databricks documentation "import dlt"

Tags: databricks

Databricks states in its documentation:

```py
import dlt
```

Without specifying what this package is or how to get it. There is a `dlt` package in pypi, but it does not have the property `table` that the `dlt` package from the documentation does.

Answer (score 0):

the `dlt` package is only available when you define a Delta Live Table workflow with python. It is not available in Pypi as of today.
[image]

[Source](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta-live-tables/python-ref.html#import-the-dlt-python-module)

Comment: Ok, so can delta live tables be defined programmatically? Do you have to use the databricks web interface?